# how to get value using preg match all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

how to get this value ?

```
background-image: url("bg.png");
```

I tried this but not working

`preg_match_all('/background-image: url("|\'|)(.*?)("|\'| );/s', $css, $getcolor1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple case, it would be enough to use `preg_match` function:

```
$str = 'background-image: url("bg.png")';
preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m);

print_r($m[1]);
```

The output:

```
bg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
<?php
$css = 'background-image: url("bg.png");background-image: url("bg_2.png");';

preg_match_all('/background-image: url\((\"|\')(.*?)(\"|\')\)/', $css, $matches);

echo 'with background-image';
print_r($matches[0]);

echo 'without background-image';
print_r($matches[2]);
```

Output:

```
with background-image:
Array
(
    [0] => background-image: url("bg.png")
    [1] => background-image: url("bg_2.png")
)

without background-image:
Array
(
    [0] => bg.png
    [1] => bg_2.png
)
```